# Bigquery data consumption

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, query-optimization

I have a big query to run. It has multiple tables joining and multiple ctes.
Before I run the query in GCP , once it's ready to run it gives me a message saying
`This script will process 30 MiB when run.`

[image]

Once I've run the query It says

```
Query complete (0.4 sec elapsed, 4.91 GB processed)
```

[image]

1. How can I reduce Bytes processed ? it's 4.91 GB now.
2. If I want to optimize a big query , where can I see the information of data consumption and time of that query's performance?

I want to optimize my query and show the results of data consumption of the query.

Comment: What's your request? What's your dataset? Let us know more to have help on that!

Comment: Could you try using [dry-run queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dry-run-queries) to estimate the number of bytes read by the query? If possible, could you also share a screenshot of the issue you are facing along with the details asked by @guillaume blaquiere?

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshots

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant Sorry I don't understand your comment

Comment: Could you provide the following details to understand your issue: what is your type of [data source](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-overview#data_sources)? If it is an [external data source](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources), are you using External tables or Federated queries?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the the time, when federated views are used in the query then there will be difference in pre-execution and post-execution stats.

In other cases it is almost same.

Comment: If I want to optimize a big query , where can I see the information of data consumption and time ?
 so I can optimize the query re run and compare the results to make sure??

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshots. can you please check them and provide a solution? thank you